# How do i count the number of occurances in my logs in cloudwatch over a date range?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I don't care about efficiency or anything at all - I just want to know how many times the term
"Hello World" appears in my logs some date range.

I tried making a "metric filter", and I did make one! - but then the UI said "you made a metric filter good job" and the tutorial i used assumed all i ever wanted was to make one, so I have no idea how to actually run it.

I don't mind doing whatever - it doesn't have to be a metric filter, I just want a simple way to do counts!

Comment: If you created metric filter, you go to CloudWatch metrics to view the custom metric. Have you checked that?

Comment: The flow is: Data sent to CloudWatch Logs -> Filtered by Metric Filter -> Stats appear in CloudWatch. You can then create an Alarm based on those stats.